# POST request not working in angular CLI version 7

Tags: angular, rxjs

When sending a `http` request I have followed [this](https://angular.io/guide/http) documentation and created following service.

I have tried using angular version 5 syntax but did not work.

```
createCartProduct(cartpr : CartProduct): Observable<CartProduct> {
    console.log("createCartProduct",cartpr);
    return this.http.post<CartProduct>(this.apiURL+'CartProduct', cartpr, this.httpOptions)
    .pipe(
      retry(1),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
  }
```

This is my entire [service](https://gist.github.com/AyeshaUOM/61cf62fdd40d6fcfdb2d17686eb554af)

And I have added it to my app module under `Providers`

`console.log` works as expected but it seems the post request is not working.

I am new to angular and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have the feeling you forgot to subscribe to your observable. The call won't be triggered until you subscribe to your Observable

Comment: Can you please explain how to do that? Or any online material?

Comment: You could maybe have a look at the documentation of RxJs : https://www.learnrxjs.io/concepts/rxjs-primer.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to subscribe to the `http.post` to get any response. Example:

```
 this.createCartProduct().subscribe((data)=> console.log(data));
```

In your scenario I would do something like this:

```
  this.http.post<CartProduct>(this.apiURL+'CartProduct', cartpr, this.httpOptions)
    .pipe(
      retry(1),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    ).pipe(take(1)).subscribe();
```

From angular docs:

> An HttpClient method does not begin its HTTP request until you call
>   subscribe() on the observable returned by that method. This is true
>   for all HttpClient methods.

https://angular.io/guide/http